# Using 'finally' to call a method by Design

Tags: java, try-catch-finally

In a `try-catch-finally` situation what is the proper way of handling `finally` when it comes to calling a method?

The reason why I ask is a Service Implementation class that makes DB calls might have a `finally` clause in every method.

If I am to use the DRY approach I don't want the `finally` clause to keep repeating the same code.

For example

```
    try {
        // DB call  
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        // Error messages etc
    } finally {
        // entityMangerProvider is a field
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerProvider.get();
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        if (entityManager.isOpen()) {
            if (transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
```

The `finally` above gets repeated through out. Is it proper to do something like this

```
private void closeEntityManager() {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerProvider.get();
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    if (entityManager.isOpen()) {
        if (transaction.isActive()) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

and then do this

```
    try {
        // DB call  
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        // Error messages etc
    } finally {
        closeEntityManager();
    }
```

Are there any drawbacks to this approach? Is there a better way of avoiding repeating the finally clause over and over again.

Project is on Java 7, if it matters.

Comment: Methods are intended for reducing code duplication. This seems like a good example of doing that.

Comment: Is there a drawback for doing it that way though? Can finally calling a method cause that method to not run properly?

Comment: No, I don't see any problems with your solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there doesn't seem to be any limitation with your new method approach. Methods can be created to provide flexibility within the code.

You only have an `entityManagerProvider` (which you can pass to this new method as a parameter, if calling from other places), and rest you're working with all newly created objects and references; so it is perfect to define the new method and call it wherever you use finally{...}.